# Making sure multiple inputs are numbers (c++)

Tags: c++, validation, istream, formatted-input

I was making a program where I asked user for a date and compared it with the current date. All the functionality was there but I couldn't seem to validate the day, month and year were numbers so entering letters crashed the program. Any ideas? (Note: the functions in the do while loop work as intended)

```
do // This do while loop forces the user to enter a valid date before moving on
    {
        cout << "Enter the lent date in the format dd/mm/yyyy: " << endl;
        cin >> day1 >> buffer >> month1 >> buffer >> year1;
        if(cin.fail())
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    while (!validateDateSize(day1, month1, year1) || !validateDateIntegrity(day1, month1, year1));
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. And learn how to use a debugger (which is a crucial tool for any programmer).

Comment: Inputs are **never** numbers; they are **text**. If you need to do detailed analysis of the input, don’t convert it directly to numbers; read it as text, do the analysis, and convert it if you’ve determined that that’s appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the definition of your variables.  Let's assume:

```
int day1, month1, year1; 
char buffer;
```

Entering a valid date such as "12/3/2017", "12-3-2017" or even "12.3.2017" would pass the test. Entering invalid dates but with a valid format such as "125.3.2017" would fail the test, and loop to offer the next chance for a correct entry.

**So what's the problem ?**

But if something goes wrong in the format, for example with "12/A/2017",  `cin` would fail at the first unexpected char (here 'A').  Your code would then `continue` the loop.  Unfortunately, the fail status of `cin` will remain unchanged, causing any subsequent input to fail and your code to loop forever.

**How to correct it ?**

You need to [`clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) the error status, and also [`ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) the wrong characters that caused the failure and are still in the input :

```
   if(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();                        //reset error flags
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');  // and ignore characters until the next newline
        continue;
    }
```

**[Online demo](https://ideone.com/h5Lgfz)**

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to put that cin.fail after inputting each int variable or is once at the end ok?

Comment: @stylersolve I've added some additional links to the functions used, as well as an online demo, where you can play with the input. DOing the test as you did is ok. The only drawback is that you will not know for sure where the failure was (e.g. was the day invalid, or the month or the year).  Several fails can help you to give more precise error messages if you'd need them.

Comment: Thank you very much! The actual error location does not matter in this instance.

Comment: When I type in a word, both the error messages stack (from the function and cin.fail). I guess I cannot avoid this?

Comment: @stylersolve this is because `continue` will ignore the rest of the loop body, but go through the condition testing (see here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue).  You can avoid this by using an  additional flag in the condition.  Example here: https://ideone.com/iAwxlc

Comment: @stylersolve alternatively you could also handle the formatting check in a similar way that you perform your other checks as shown here:  https://ideone.com/ffcOId

Comment: I used the first method with an extra flag because it seemed to fit better. The problem is fixed now so thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any validation, check whether the input received from user is a digit or not.

```
isdigit(char c)
```

Checks whether c is a decimal digit character.

**Return Value :**
A value different from zero (i.e., true) if indeed c is a decimal digit. Zero (i.e., false) otherwise.

Comment: Does that work for integers (or do I need to cast), and what if the number is more than one character e.g. 11?

Comment: It works for characters , so you need to scan character by character.

Comment: How would I join the characters together to make an integer? e.g. '2' and '1' to make 21

Comment: That's another approach.  Unfortunately, your answer is not sufficient as it is: it would required to take the input in a string and parse it char by char.  Can you elaborate on your answer to provide a working solution ?